# PowerShell select-object Expand Property For multiple values

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How can I Filter **Files Name** and Complete **Files Path** Using powershell select-object expand property here is files in partition

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----          3/9/2021   1:14 AM            pics
-a---         1/14/2021   4:35 PM      59929 151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg
-a---         1/14/2021   4:35 PM      80949 151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg
-a---         1/14/2021   4:35 PM      85725 151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
-a---         1/14/2021   4:35 PM      80519 151104051640IMG_20151103_123924.jpg
```

**Command to Filter Files Name**

```
PS O:\> dir | select -expandproperty name
```

**Output**

```
pics
151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg
151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg
151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
151104051640IMG_20151103_123924.jpg
151104051658IMG_20151103_130741.jpg
151104051712IMG_20151103_130756.jpg
151104051721IMG_20151103_131053.jpg
151104051853IMG_20151103_090959.jpg
```

But I also want **Full Files Paths** with Every File Name i am using this command but receiving an error

```
PS O:\> dir | select -expandproperty Name,FullName
Or
PS O:\> dir | select -expand Name,FullName
Or 
PS O:\> dir | %{$_.Name} %{$_.FullName}

Error:

Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'.
Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:30
```

How can i filter multiple Properties Values is there any simple way? i want only values excluding properties names like

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     -----------
```

want output something like this:

```
151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg   o:\151104051548IMG_20151103_112015.jpg 
151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg   o:\151104051558IMG_20151103_123234.jpg 
151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg   o:\151104051610IMG_20151103_123249.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should print it how you want:

`get-childitem "O:\" | % { Write-Host $_.Name,$_.FullName }`

And if you want all files, for example, even in the \pics\ folder, you can add `-recurse` right before the pipe.

`get-childitem "O:\" -recurse | % { Write-Host $_.Name,$_.FullName }`

Comment: Thanks For your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$> dir . | select name, fullname | ogv
$> get-childitem . | select name, fullname | out-gridview
```